# Assign access to users AAD application powershell or Graph API

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to give access to users on an application on AAD by powershell or Graph API. I have a list of 60 users and I don't want to do it by hand. I've investigate in AAD cmdleds but I didn't find anything useful for me. Is there any way for doing that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: have you looked at [Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj151815.aspx)

Comment: Yes I did but I haven't found anyting for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so through PowerShell with a module from this [blog post](http://www.edutech.me.uk/administration/script-bulk-assign-users-to-saas-application-using-graph-api-adal/). 
After you download the module, edit it, create a csv file containing your 60 users, run 4 cmdlets and you're done!

(Remember to restart PowerShell if you make an edit to the psm1 module in the middle of a PowerShell session, reimporting doesn't clear the cache.)